# NGINX downloads PHP files insted of executing

Tags: nginx, php

I tried everything and searched everywhere.

I'm following this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04

My config file:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name your_domain www.your_domain;
root /var/www/your_domain;

index index.html index.htm index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
 }

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

}
```

I created a info.php file.
When I visit mydomain.com/info.php it download the file instead of executing it.
Already cleared browser cache, also in NGINX.

Comment: I just saw that in the configuration file the character "~" is missing for the 2 "location" config.
Could it be the error?

Comment: It may, but it also means you did not copy and paste the contents of your config file into the question, which will make it exceptionally difficult to successfully answer your question.

Comment: Check if php-fpm is actually started: `systemctl status php7.4-fpm.service` then have a look at the log files.

Comment: @digijay yes, I already checked also the path

Comment: @Paul I'm searching a solution to paste the tilde

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself.
Here is the solution:

I double checked the configuration file uploaded to my server and I found that 2 tilde were missing after the "location" config.
I just added them and everything is working